# Android - Methods in DialogListener attached to Facebook.authorize() not getting hit

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook Android SDK in my app, but I can't seem to get the most basic authentication working. I've got my project setup, my Facebook App ID, everything as required.

I kick off the Facebook authentication with a simple OnClickListener():

```
    signIn_Facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.i("MyTag", "Facebook authorize about to start.");
            facebook.authorize(SignIn.this, new FacebookLoginDialogListener());
        }

    });
```

My problem is that none of the methods in the DialogListener ever get called:

```
private class FacebookLoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
{
        Log.i("MyTag", "Facebook authorize complete.");

}

@Override
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {                              
    Log.i("MyTag", "Facebook authorize facebook error.");
}

@Override
public void onError(DialogError e) 
{
        Log.i("MyTag", "Facebook authorize dialog error.");

}

@Override
public void onCancel() 
{
        Log.i("MyTag", "Facebook authorize cancel.");
}
}
```

When this code runs on the app, the Facebook dialog opens up, you can sign in, and then it just closes - no errors - however none of the log message (or breakpoints) in the FacebookLoginDialogListener class ever get called.

I feel as though I'm missing something really obvious. Thanks...

### SOLVED

Just needed to add:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

private Facebook mFb;
private String[] mPermissions;

mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, new LoginDialogListener());

If you want an example check out https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/LoginButton.java

Anything else, just ask ;)

Comment: Sorry, didn't help. No difference at all.

Comment: mhm, could you provide me the full class code with the onclick? i havent used fb sdk before but I could help searching for a solution

Comment: Thanks for your help, I simply didn't have the `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }` line... how embarrasing